# WebService Certificate Validation using WebSphere, Spring-WS and WSS4J

Tags: web-services, websphere, ws-security, spring-ws, truststore

i'm working on a webapp offering SOAP WebServices using Spring-WS 2.0. The WebService Requests need to be signed with a certificate which is of course validated on the server. In order to do this WSS4J and a truststore is used - here the spring-config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="validationActions" value="Signature" />
    <property name="validationSignatureCrypto">
      <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="pass"/>
        <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="location"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The application should be deployed to WebSphere 7 and the major requirement is, that the truststore should not be shipped with the application but be provided by the Application Server.
Does anybody know how i can achieve, that WebSphere either provides the truststore or how WebSphere can be configured to perform the security authorization ? The major challenge seems to be, that Spring-WS is used instead of using the WebSphere's facility for WebServices...

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Spring-WS so don't know the details of it.

WAS has a truststore which is where the list of trusted signer certificates are stored.

THe keystores and truststores can kept @ multiple levels if you desire (e.g node,cell etc).

For detailed info you can look at a publicly available PPT

http://www.websphereusergroup.org.uk/wug/files/presentations/25/25_3_WAS61SecUpdate.pdf.

I don't know the version of WAS that you are using WAS 6.1 and WAS 7.x are the most widely used ones these days!

HTH
Manglu

Comment: okay - and once i've uploaded my certificate to the key-/truststore how can i obtain it in my application ?

Comment: Hi Odalf, I am not sure i understand your comment. Why would your application need the certificate in your application. You delegate the authentication to the WAS runtime (this is what i understood from your question). If you can rephrase your query i can possibly try and help out.